# Не могу найти ошибку в коде.При выполнении зацикливается

Tags: c#

```
//Цифровой корень 
int a = 525;
string s = a.ToString();
int[] k = new int[s.Length];
int sum = 0;
do
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        k[i] = int.Parse(s[i].ToString());
        sum = sum + k[i];
    }

} while (sum > 11);


Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Comment: значение sum только увеличивается, поэтому если на первой итерации значение было больше 11 - цикл никогда не закончится

Comment: А что должен делать этот код? Что за задачу он решает?

Answer (score 1):

```
while (sum >= 11); //Если sum больше или равна 11 останавливаем цикл.
```

Так как sum больше 11 цикл никогда не остановится.